# Как работает .append в JS?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста на примере такой разметки:

```
<div  '.$title.' '.$bg.' >
                <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                  <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left"> </span>
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">
<form  method="post" action="">
<b> '.$p.' <i>'.$result['tema'].'  </i></b> '.$sta.'  '.$datetime.' </span>
</form> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                  <img class="direct-chat-img"  src="/img/'.$result['foto'].'.jpg" alt="Message User Image"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                  <div class="direct-chat-text">
               '.$result['mes'].' 

                  </div>
                  <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.direct-chat-msg -->
                </div>
```

В script указан div для отображения, я так понимаю нужно что то типо:

```
 $("#dtr").append("указать div с id записи или как?");
```

Если html указать, то дублирует

```
   function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "../../ajax/select/dialog.php",  
            cache: true,  
            success: function(html){
                $("#dtr").append(html); 
            }  
        });  
    }  

      $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',3000);  
    });
```

Спасибо)

Comment: напишите, что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: @Igor Вывод сообщений через каждые 3 сек, так что бы не просто всё обновлялось, а именно добавление. Сейчас использую $("#dtr").html(html); и при таком раскладе текст не выделить, так как обновляется всё.

Comment: чем Вас не устраивает `append`?

Comment: @Igor Вот смотрю на function addParagraph(i) и что я должен делать с этой функцией? Выводить "<p>test " + i + "</p>" ? Я хочу что был вывод из dialog.php, тем и не устраивает наверно, хочется понять как указать js что бы он не обновлял всё, а добавлял новое из php, собственно в этом и вопрос был

Comment: чем Вас не устраивает тот `append`, который сейчас у Вас в коде?

Comment: разве он не добавляет то, что Вы возвращаете из php?

Comment: @Igor Дублирует все записи каждые 3 секунды

Comment: убери `cache:true`

Comment: @Grundy убрал, изменений нет. с $("#dtr").html(html); так же обновляет всё, с  $("#dtr").append(html); так же дублирует

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев, если append **добавляет** одинаковые элементы - очевидно ты шлешь их с сервера. Следовательно проблема не в append, а в методе на сервере.

Comment: @Grundy Не спорю, учитывая что пару месяцев как увлёкся этим делом, то конечно я много не понимаю. Можно пример с выводом из бд через js?

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев, у тебя в вопросе уже вполне пример есть: ты так же шлешь запрос, сервер его обрабатывает, ходит он при этом в базу или нет, зависит только от сервера.